# Как победить «дрожащий» input после наведения?

Tags: html, css, transition

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от такого бага: 
[Видео 15 секунд](https://www.loom.com/share/3c3cc4fdc0ac42dbaa5e94b9bb269843)
При отведении курсора с инпута, если использовать transition, происходит его расширение, см.видео.

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался. Вопрос был в разнице размеров исходного и при наведении. Решается установкой одинаковых высот в данном случае. Всем спасибо!)